# SMS listener by private methods in IOS React Native application

Tags: ios, react-native, sms

It seems that Apple is very strict about allowing access to SMS data and SMS listeners. Some people have stated that there are 'hacky' solutions with private methods that will flag you in the IOS app, but they don't elaborate. Being rejected in the store would not be a problem, since my client does not want to share it on the store. A solid example of how this can be implemented (WITHOUT jail breaking the phone) would be amazing.

I want to get all SMS data, failing that, I want to listen for incoming and outgoing SMS's while the app is running on the background.